# String input matched against a binary field in SQL WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the scenario:
I have a SQL select statement that returns a binary data object as a string.  This cannot be changed it is outside the area of what I can modify.
So for example it would return '1628258DB0DD2F4D9D6BC0BF91D78652'.

If I manually add a 0x in front of this string in a query I will retrieve the results I'm looking for so for example:
SELECT a, b FROM mytable WHERE uuid = 0x1628258DB0DD2F4D9D6BC0BF91D78652
My result set is correct.

However I need to find a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 compatible means to do this programatically.  Simply concatenating 0x to the string variable does not work.  Obvious, but I did try it.

Help please :)
Thank you
Mark

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your question is that you have a column `uuid`, which is `binary`.

You are trying to select rows with a particular value in `uuid`, but you are trying to use a string like so:

`SELECT a, b FROM mytable WHERE uuid = '0x1628258DB0DD2F4D9D6BC0BF91D78652'`

which does not work.  If this is correct, you can use the [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function with a style of 2 to have SQL Server treat the string as hex and not require a `'0x'` as the first characters:

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM mytable 
WHERE uuid = CONVERT(binary(16), '1628258DB0DD2F4D9D6BC0BF91D78652', 2)
```